# ResourceManager returns name of file

Tags: c#, .net-core, resourcemanager, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .net-core 2.0 console application.
This application references a .net-standard-2.0 library with one resource file SqlStatements.resx, which contains multiple sql files.

Config of the file:
Embedded resource;
Do not copy;
ResXFileCodeGenerator;

If I call this local in Visual Studio 2017 in debug or in release mode

```
var result = SqlStatements.somefileName;
```

I get the content of the file.
But If start the code on the server, I get something like:

```
resources\somefileName.sql;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8
```

I start the application this way:

```
dotnet MyApp.Console.dll
```

Do you know what could be the reason of it?

UPDATE:
The code is correct:
I've checked with dotpeek the dlls. If I run the script:

```
dotnet build SolutionName.sln --configuration -Release
```

then the value in the resource.resx looks looks like

```
resources\somefileName.sql;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8
```

If I make a build in Visual Studio, the resx is ok (I see the content of the sql files).

Comment: May you try use this `using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(resxFile))` and then `var text = resxSet.GetString("Title");`

Comment: hi @AntonGorbunov unfortunately ResXResourceSet is from WinForms. And I have a .net-core 2.0 console application

Answer (score 0):

It worked locally because Visual Studio uses MsBuild and ist able to work with embedded resource. I've moved the sqls to code

Comment: It does not answer the question, it's a workaround.